# List<T> of particular type causes ComboBox to break

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, subsonic, equals

I have a `List<T>` which holds entity types generated by SubSonic. Let's call this type `NaughtyItem`.  When the list of `NaughtyItem` is bound to the ComboBox, strange things start to happen*.  The ComboBox is bound one way to the collection like so:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Model.NaughtyCollection,Source={StaticResource ModelSource}}" Width="120" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
```

*The first time an item is selected, the selection changes.  Once I have changed the item though, I can't select items again.  I subscribed to the `SelectionChanged` event, and it fires ones and that is it. I've solved the problem by creating a wrapper type

```
public class NaughtyWrapper
{
   public NaughtyItem {get;set;}
}
```

My guess would be that something NaughtyItem is doing is causing the ComboBox to crash and burn. I've turned on all CLR exceptions in VisualStudio, but I don't get any interesting exceptions that would explain why the unwrapped NaughtyItems are causing issues.

Anyone come across anything like this before?

Comment: how are you handling the selected item? I do not see the SelectedItem property bound in the combobox

Comment: Check that `NaughtyItem.Equals` is correctly implemented.

Comment: are you using any data template or any other style?

Comment: Echo comment from Nicholas.  If all or multiple items are evaluating to equal then you would get this behavior.   Try a HashSet as it will reject Equal items and see if it is the same length.  I had a list of string with two the same and got this behavior as string overrides equals with a string comparison.

Comment: @Nicolas Bingo. That was it.  I just commented out the overriden equals in the generated entity code and it now works.  Just answered the question, but if you provide a better answer than the one I gave I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit goes to Nicolas Repiquet for the answer.

The entities in SubSonic have a custom implementation of `Equals()` which is the cause of this problem.  Deleting the custom implementation solves the issue, though I will still use my original solution of the wrapped SubSonic entities since I don't want to mess with the framework.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj){
    if(obj.GetType()==typeof(NaughtyItem)){
        NaughtyItem compare=(NaughtyItem)obj;
        return compare.KeyValue()==this.KeyValue();
    }else{
        return base.Equals(obj);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In case Nicholas does not answer.

What I suspect is that multiple items have the the same KeyValue.

I suggest you check your configuration to generate unique KeyValue as duplicate keys could cause other errors.
Wrapping it is just masking the problem.

When you select an item in the UI it compares that to the currently selected item.
If they are the Equal it assumes that item is already selected and does nothing.

When you wrapped it you got GetHashCode and Equals from Object and object gives the correct answer (every object is unique).

Comment: In my test there were only 3 records in the DB and I am 100% sure there are no duplicates. Also 100% sure there weren't any duplicate items in the List<T>. We're also using auto increment fields as the PK, so this use case shouldn't even come up. I will look at the KeyValue stuff if I have time though.  For now, the wrapping approach seems to work and the unit tests are passing.

Comment: Wow, if there were not duplicates then this is strange.  I would debug Equals to see if Equals is getting called and the values for KeyValue.